# how to remove a attribute from XML and remove the root element from XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove a attribute and root element from XML

Input XML:

```
<OrderList>
    <Order>
        <Extn ExtnTest="" ExtnVoid="" />
    </Order>
</OrderList>
```

Expected XML is

```
<Order>
    <Extn ExtnTest=""  />
</Order>
```

So I want to remove the root element (OrderList) and attribute (ExtnVoid)

I am using the below XSL but it isnt working pls help

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/OrderList/@ExtnVoid" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/OrderList/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the identity transform, you can remove the wrapper by applying templates just to child elements, and then eating the unwanted attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/OrderList">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@ExtnVoid" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```